# Default values parameters not taken into account in C#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have downloaded the QRCoder sources  and I have compiled the sources with Visual studio 2019.
Then I add a reference on my Visual stuio 2008 project to the generated QRCODER.dll from the folder "net35".

Then I try to start a smal demo:

```cs
QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode("The text which should be encoded.",         
QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
```

The compiler gives an error saying there is no method match found (I only pass a string and an errorlevel). In the source I see the method signature with default values :

```cs
public QRCodeData CreateQrCode(string plainText, ECCLevel eccLevel, bool forceUtf8 = false, bool utf8BOM = false, EciMode eciMode = EciMode.Default, int requestedVersion = -1)
{
    return GenerateQrCode(plainText, eccLevel, forceUtf8, utf8BOM, eciMode, requestedVersion);
}
```

So the question is: Why I cannot invoke the method with only 2 paramters (string and error level) ?

My solution is to explicitly add a method with 2 arguments (in the source file) and from the body of this method make a call to the method with the default values. After that, I compile and reference the dll in my project in Visual studio 2008 and now, the compiler does not give the error anymore .... Does support theframework.net 3.5 default value in the method ... or ... ?

```
  /// <summary>
        /// Calculates the QR code data which than can be used in one of the rendering classes to generate a graphical representation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="plainText">The payload which shall be encoded in the QR code</param>
        /// <param name="eccLevel">The level of error correction data</param>
        /// <param name="forceUtf8">Shall the generator be forced to work in UTF-8 mode?</param>
        /// <param name="utf8BOM">Should the byte-order-mark be used?</param>
        /// <param name="eciMode">Which ECI mode shall be used?</param>
        /// <param name="requestedVersion">Set fixed QR code target version.</param>
        /// <exception cref="QRCoder.Exceptions.DataTooLongException">Thrown when the payload is too big to be encoded in a QR code.</exception>
        /// <returns>Returns the raw QR code data which can be used for rendering.</returns>
        public QRCodeData CreateQrCode(string plainText, ECCLevel eccLevel, bool forceUtf8 = false, bool utf8BOM = false, EciMode eciMode = EciMode.Default, int requestedVersion = -1)
        {
            return GenerateQrCode(plainText, eccLevel, forceUtf8, utf8BOM, eciMode, requestedVersion);
        }

        public QRCodeData CreateQrCode(string plainText, ECCLevel eccLevel)
        {
            return GenerateQrCode(plainText, eccLevel);
        }
```

Comment: Please use the preview to check that your post is readable before you submit it. None of your code was formatted correctly, because you'd used apostrophes instead of backticks. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more details on formatting posts.

Comment: Microsoft often changes parameters of methods from one version of Net to next version of Net.

Comment: @jdweng: No, they really don't. Microsoft is really pretty strict about backward compatibility. And note that this isn't about a method in the .NET Framework anyway - it's about the OP's method. The problem is simply that optional parameters aren't supported in C# 3.

Comment: @JonSkeet : Really?  When going from Net 3.5 to Net 4.0 you had to add to SMTP Nnetwork Credentials in Net 4.0 but didn't in Net 3.5. And what about Cryptography and TLS?  Don't say Microsoft is strict about backward compatibility.  It is Microsoft last concerns.  It has been a mess since last June when the did a security upgrade to TLS server disabling TLS 1.0 and 1.1 and not having any solution for the clients.  I've answered 3 or 4 posting a day on the issue.

Comment: @jdweng: None of those are "changing parameters of methods" - and it's entirely reasonable IMO to remove support for old and insecure protocols, when the alternative is security breaches. Is backward compatibility perfect? Nope. Is Microsoft pretty strict about it? Absolutely - they do an amazing job of it considering the *huge* surface area they're covering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does support the framework.net 3.5 default value in the method

The .NET Framework supports optional parameters in version 3.5 (in terms of the attributes being part of the framework), but the C# 3 compiler (which is what Visual Studio 2008 uses) doesn't. Optional parameters and named arguments were introduced in C# 4.

I would strongly recommend using a modern version of Visual Studio, even if you still need to target ancient versions of .NET. (I'd also strongly recommend moving off unsupported versions of .NET if at all possible.)